# Run any service in background on PlayFramework 2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Currently I'm using a Module using bind asEagerSingleton to run a code right after application is started, but when I try to access any controller class, it say the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.

Is there any other approach to do this.

thx

Comment: could you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you try to run your service synchronously that prevents application start. Try to schedule your background task on executor from Akka or create a new one (not recommended).

Comment: Yes, I got that problem. Now I'm scheduling the background task using Akka, however I dont have access to Http Context.

Comment: Could you please post your? It will speed up.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this question hope my answer fullfill your requirement.
[Play 2.5 - Run a Java method at certain times of day (cron)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139866/play-2-5-run-a-java-method-at-certain-times-of-day-cron)