# Play 2.5 - Run a Java method at certain times of day (cron)

Tags: java, scala, cron, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm working on a Play 2.5 app that needs to run a method at midday, 2pm, 4pm every day autonomously.

So far I have followed [another answer on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842293/java-playframework-globalsettings-deprecation-for-onstart) which has got me most of the way. The application.conf file has been updated to look at the  Module file, which binds to the OnStartup() method correctly.

I believe the issue is to do with the code in the OnStartup() method, I've included the code below - is this the correct way to get something to run at certain times of day?

```
package controllers;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;

import java.util.Calendar;


@Singleton
public class OnStartup {

    @Inject
    public OnStartup() {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        String hour = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        String minute = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        String dateTime = hour + ":" + minute;
        String time = "12:00";
        String time1 = "14:00";
        String time2 = "16:00";

        if (dateTime.equals(time) || dateTime.equals(time1) || dateTime.equals(time2)){
            System.out.print(dateTime);
            myAmazingClass.doSomethingWonderful();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Akka `Scheduler` can be used: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/?_ga=1.256176713.331620270.1455976396#akka.actor.Scheduler

Comment: I use an AWS Lambda function to trigger certain end points (with secret query string and a couple of other security blocks), that's really easy - and means that the procedure is only called once rather than once for every machine running the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your approach you need three things Module,actor,and a scheduler.

### Step1: Create Actor

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import play.Logger;

public class DoSomethingActor extends UntypedActor{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Object message) throws Throwable {
        Logger.info("Write your crone task or simply call your method here that perform your task"+message);

    }

}
```

### Step2:Create scheduler

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Cancellable;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;

@Singleton
public class DoSomethingScheduler {

    @Inject
    public DoSomethingScheduler(final ActorSystem system,
            @Named("do-something-actor") final ActorRef doSomethingActor) {
        final Cancellable scheduler;
        final int timeDelayFromAppStart = 0;
        final int timeGapInSeconds = 1; //Here you provide the time delay for every run
        system.scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(timeDelayFromAppStart, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), //Initial delay when system start
                Duration.create(timeGapInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS),     //Frequency delay for next run
                doSomethingActor,
                "message for onreceive method of doSomethingActor",
                system.dispatcher(),
                null);
    }
}
```

### Step3: Bind your scheduler and actor with module.

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

import play.libs.akka.AkkaGuiceSupport;

public class SchedulerModule extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        this.bindActor(DoSomethingActor.class, "do-something-actor");
        this.bind(DoSomethingScheduler.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

### Step4: Configure your module in aaplication.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.rits.modules.SchedulerModule"
```

Make sure that no need to worry about onStart module leave that as usual, this module is only serving your purpose of scheduling task.